# React native FlatList onEndReached() trigered automaticly

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am working on a `react native` project
I got a problem loading more data using `<FlatList>`

When I set the height of the parent component `<View>` 500 as my code show, the scroll function is abnormal. I can not scroll up and down freely with leftmouse in the simulator or finger in the real phone, the window of `ScrollView` is limited to 500

When I do not set the height of parent component  or set height 100%, then I can scroll up and down without any limitation, but `onEndReached()` triggered automatically every sec as my code. actually, I do not scroll at all

**It is my code:**

```js
     data = [{ID: '1', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '-10', STATUS: '0'}, 
                {ID: '2', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '0'},
                {ID: '3', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '4', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '5', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '6', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '7', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '8', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '9', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'},
                {ID: '10', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: '+100.00', STATUS: '1'}            
                ]


    _renderItem = (item) => {
        let { ID, TITLE, DATE, VALUE, STATUS } = item.item
        return (
            <View key={ID} style={{backgroundColor: 'white',alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',marginBottom: 1, height: (widthScroll / widthConst) * 138}}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
            activeOpacity={1}
            style={{width:  (widthScroll / widthConst) * 700}}
        >
            <View style={{}}> 
                <View style={{}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: (widthScroll / widthConst) * 32, color: '#333333'}}>{TITLE}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: (widthScroll / widthConst) * 40, color: '#333333'}}>{VALUE}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginTop:  (widthScroll / widthConst) * 3}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: (widthScroll / widthConst) * 28, color: '#888888'}}>{DATE}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: (widthScroll / widthConst) * 28, color: '#888888')}}>{STATUS}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
        );
    }




    _onLoadMore = () => {
        this.timer1 = setTimeout(()=>{
            let dataExtra = [{ID: '11', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: this.state.count, STATUS: '0'}]
            let data = this.state.data.concat(dataExtra);
            this.setState({data:data, count: this.state.count + 1});
        }, 1000);
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, height: 500}}>
                <View style={{height: '100%'}}>
                    <FlatList
                    ref={(c)=>this.flatList=c}
                    style={{flex:1}}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    data={this.state.data}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
                    onEndReached={() => this._onLoadMore()}
            />    
                </View>
                
            </View>
            
        );
    }
```

Comment: The platform is Android, IOS is normal

Answer (score 0):

try this code.....

```
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
if(distanceFromEnd >= 0) {
     //Call pagination function
}
}}
```

**Alternatively**

`onMomentumScrollEnd` rather than `onEndReached`, like this:

```
  onMomentumScrollEnd={() => { // fetchData}}
```

It might not be written as the available `prop` in the react-native documentation, but if you will see the source code for `FlatList`, it uses `Virtualized List` **which in return has the mentioned prop available**.

Comment: Without height, onEndReached() still trigered automaticly

Comment: By replacing onEndReached with onMomentumScrollEnd, onMomentumScrollEnd() won't be trigered

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onEndReached={() => data.length >= pageSize && this._onLoadMore()}    


 _onLoadMore = () => {
        this.timer1 = setTimeout(()=>{
            let dataExtra = [{ID: '11', TITLE: 'sold', DATE: '2019-05-23 12:13', VALUE: this.state.count, STATUS: '0'}]
            let data = this.state.data.concat(dataExtra);
            this.setState({data:data, pageSize:this.state.pageSize + 10, count: this.state.count + 1});
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: What about 'data.length >= pageSize' mean? data.length will increase after this._onLoadMore() executed and pageSize is a constant. It is always true

Comment: no when screen load data 0 and pageSize 10 
then condition false

after _onLoadMore call data tobe 10 and pageSize  to be 20

onEndReached function are  call if array of last index visible on screen